# php mysql using nested query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to find if two runners have ever ran in the same race. The two runners are Peter Smith and Diane Peters.

```
$resultRaceType = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT  DISTINCT date,time FROM results where runner = 'Peter, Smith' ");   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultRaceType )) 
{
    $resultRaceType1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT  * FROM results where date = ' " . $row['date'] . " ' and time = ' " . $row['time'] . " ' and runner = 'Diane, Peters'");   
    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultRaceType1 )) 
    {
        echo "<tr >";   
        echo "<td>"; 
        echo $row1['date'];
        echo " - " . $row1['time'];
        echo "</td>";   
        echo "<tr>";    
    }    
}
```

The above code works, but only if I limit the first select to LIMIT 50. So I can see that it is timing out. My table has over 100K rows. I know I am doing something wrong but cant see what it is.
Thanks for any help you guy's can give me.

Comment: You should probably join the table on itself using the different conditions.

Comment: It's a bad idea to load a 100k rows table on dom.. You should consider server side pagination and fetch results in batches.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.** Such as the extra spaces as where you're quoting your variables.

Comment: @aynber Depends... he might aswell not be vulnerable to SQL injection, we can't know that from his code.

Comment: This could be acheived using only one query with joins and ordering. You could try that.

Comment: @Xatenev SQL injection, probably not. Quoting headaches, most likely. I'm sure those extra spaces inside the quotes here `date = ' " . $row['date'] . " '` aren't helping anything.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I will take all of your comments on board, they are very welcome and help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT a.date, a.time FROM results a
    JOIN results b ON (a.date = b.date AND a.time = b.time)
    WHERE a.runner='Peter, Smith' AND b.runner='Diane, Peters';
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough wordragon, works brilliantly.  You are a star.